# Using two types of grouping, one for plotting line one for color in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib, colors, pandas-groupby

I'm new to any type of coding so please bear with me.
I plot a set of data with originally 33 columns into a plot using `df.groupby`.
This is so that I have multiple lines, each line representing the change over time of a particular sample. With my method each line has a unique color.
I want the lines which have the same value in the Column 'Storage Temperature' to have the same color in the plot.

This is my code so far:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame([['Glass', 'BK1', 150, 48, 15],
                   ['Metal', 'BK1', 150, 48, 23],
                   ['Glass', 'BK1', 120, 48, 12],
                   ['Glass', 'BK2', 120, 48, 13],
                   ['Glass', 'BK1', 150, 200, 18],
                   ['Metal', 'BK1', 150, 200, 26],
                   ['Glass', 'BK1', 120, 100, 17],
                   ['Glass', 'BK2', 120, 100, 14],
                   ['Glass', 'BK1', 150, 250, 20],
                   ['Metal', 'BK1', 150, 270, 27],
                   ['Glass', 'BK1', 120, 150, 25],
                   ['Glass', 'BK2', 120, 150, 16]],
                  columns=['Material', 'Colour', 'Storage Temperature',
                            'Storage Time', 'Result'])

groups = df.groupby(['Material', 'Colour', 'Storage Temperature'])

fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 9))

for element, group in groups:
        group.plot(x='Storage Time', y='Result', ax=ax,
                   marker= 'o',
                   linestyle='-',
                   ms=10, fontsize=20,
                   label='%s %s, %s°C'
                   % (group.iloc[0]['Material'],
                      group.iloc[0]['Colour'],
                      group.iloc[0]['Storage Temperature']))
plt.show()
```

This is what I get: https://i.stack.imgur.com/OqUgY.png

I've tried with

```
sns.lineplot('Storage Time', 'Result', data=groups,
             hue='Storage Temperature', estimator=None)
```

instead of `group.plot` but I get an error: Cannot access callable attribute 'get' of 'DataFrameGroupBy' objects, try using the 'apply' method

How can I get this right?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Please take a moment to read [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). You need to provide a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) that includes a toy dataset (refer to [How to make good reproducible pandas examples](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20109391/how-to-make-good-reproducible-pandas-examples))

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a quick fix using `matplotlib colormaps`:

```
import pandas as pd
from matplotlib import cm

groups = df.groupby(['Material', 'Colour', 'Storage Temperature'])
fig, ax = plt.subplots(figsize=(15, 9))

max_T = max(df['Storage Temperature'])
cmap = cm.get_cmap('viridis')
for element, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group['Storage Time'], group['Result'], marker = 'o', ms = 10, 
            label = element[0]+', '+element[1]+' '+element[2] + '°C', color = 
            cmap(element[2]/max_T))
plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Alternatively, write a little function that selects colors for you

```
def colorselector(temp):
    if temp == 150:
        return 'red'
    elif temp == 120:
        return 'blue'
    elif temp == ... :
        return 'green'
    ...

for element, group in groups:
    ax.plot(group['Storage Time'], group['Result'], marker = 'o', ms =10, 
    label = element[0]+', '+element[1]+' '+str(element[2]) +'°C',
    color = colorselector(element[2]))

plt.legend()
plt.show()
```

Your `colorselector` could also use a cmap to get pretty colors :)